# T-SQL to loop through records in one table and modify field value based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 2 tables. `TableA` has a series of products with costs and `TableB` has a series of multipliers based on dates. For example:

**TableA** (Key: Product)

```
Product ID     Cost   Multiplier Code
ProductA       100    ABC
ProductB       200    DEF
ProductC       300    ABC
ProductD       400    JKL
```

**TableB** (Key: Date, Code)

```
Date        Code   Multiplier
01/01/12    ABC    100
01/01/12    DEF    200
01/01/12    GHI    300
01/01/12    JKL    400
16/03/12    ABC    300
20/06/12    ABC    900
15/05/12    DEF    700
```

**Desired results:**

**TableA** (Key: Product)

```
Product ID     Cost      Multiplier Code
ProductA       90000     ABC
ProductB       140000    DEF
ProductC       270000    ABC
ProductD       160000    JKL
```

What I would like to do is write a T-SQL script which loops through ALL of `TableA` and at the same time, ***multiply up*** the `Cost` column using `TableB` multipliers. So in the example of **ProductA** above, `Cost` should become `100 x 900 = 90,000`.

It needs to use the latest modifier based on the date in `TableB` hence using 900 as the modifier.

Is this possible?

Comment: For Product `ABC` there are three corresponding rows in `TableB`, how the COST is computed for the two differenet `ABC`s products in tableA, one became 90000 and the other became 270000 Why???

Comment: @MahmoudGamal because he is multiplying `100 with 900 =90000` then `300 with 900 = 270000` where `900` is the `max value` for 'ABC' from secondtable.

Comment: @ViswanathanIyer, Since it is the `max value` not the `max date` then you have to explain this in the answer, since all the below answers are selecting the multiplying factor based on the `max date`.

Comment: As you've probably noticed from the posted answers, none of them are "looping through" the rows of one table - and that's because that's not how SQL should work. You try to write statements that describe the *complete* result set you're aiming for, and then let SQL Server work out how best to perform data access to achieve that end.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal, I am slightly confused, should I not be using `max date`? For ProductA, it should always pick the latest multiplier regardless of value. By latest I mean the date closest to today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update TableA
set a.Cost = a.Cost * aux2.Multiplier
from TableA a
inner join 
(select b.Code, b.Multiplier from TableB b
 inner join
    (select max(Date) as 'Date', Code
    from TableB
    group by Code) aux on b.Date = aux.Date and b.Code = aux.Code
) aux2 on aux2.Code = a.MultiplierCode
```

`aux` gets the max Date for a given Code.
`aux2` gets the multiplier for the dates in `aux`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
UPDATE  a
SET     Cost *= _b.Multiplier
FROM    a
JOIN    (
    SELECT  Code,
            Multiplier,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY Date DESC) RowNum
    FROM    b
) _b ON _b.Code = a.Code AND _b.RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.productid,
       p.cost * m.multiplier,
       p.multiplier_code
from tableA p
  join (
    select b1.multiplier, b1.code
    from tableB b1
    where b1.date = (select max(b2.date)
                     from tableB b2
                     where b2.code = b1.code)
  ) m on p.multiplier_code = m.code
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Product 
SET COST = COST *
(
    SELECT TOP 1 Multiplier 
    FROM Date_Code 
    WHERE Product.MultiplierCode = Date_Code.Code
    ORDER BY CodeDate DESC
)
```